# if condition only few steps true VBA/Excel

Tags: excel, vba

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ED5oS.png)For a larger project I need to change the source of values for a column all n*k steps, with n being a rational and k a natural number.

Edit for better understanding:
I have a column with multiple entries (filled by a loop in a makro) and need to find all entries with a common divisor called "testwer" in my makro. This "testwer" should later be editable in an excel sheet via a cellinput (in this case G2)

I've tried by writing a macro , a simplified example looks like the following:

```
Sub testmam()
  Dim testwer, i, j
  i = 1
  j = 1
  testwer = Range("g2").Value 'gets the rational number n

  Do Until i = 18 'until end of entries in column is reached
    If Cells(i, 1).Value = testwer * j Then 'if cellvalue = n*1,2,...,infty
      Cells(i, 2).Value = j 'some output in another cell to check wether the detection was sucessfull
      j = j + 1 'check coming cells for next value of n*k
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Loop
End Sub
```

However, when I run this, it only detects the first few (3-5) solutions. For example for n being 1.5 it found only 1.5, 3 and 4.5 to be true. Starting from values 6 to all following multipliers of 1.5 the if condition seems to turn out false.

Does someone know how this could happen? As the if condition is true for multiple steps, I assume the syntax isn't completely wrong.

Greets

Comment: I don't understand "n" that you keep referring to. What is that and how does it figure into this code? You say it here: *"change the source of values for a column all n*k steps"* (which this sentence makes no sense to me). You say it here: *"For example for n being 1.5 it found only 1.3, 3 and 4.5 to be true."* What, in your code, or in your workbook is "n"? "testwer"?

Comment: Sharing a screenshot of your data with the desired result could be very helpful.

Comment: excuse me, im quite new to excel and did a little typo here. Also im more used to express stuff in mathematical/theoretical ways.
i just called it n due to being used to it from university (we always got refered to variable rational or natural numbers by either k or n), in my makro the variable is called testwer, and its value is something that the user can enter in the Interface/Excel table. for my typo: with tester/n being 1.5, i only got the values 1.5, 3 and 4.5 as true. Screenshot will follow.

Comment: `Do Until i = 19` will do the trick in this particular case. I'll post something in half an hour or so.

Answer (score 0):

### Detect Multipliers

**Compact**

```vb
Sub TestMamCompact()
      
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SourceFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    Const TestCellAddress As String = "G2"
    Const DestinationColumn As String = "B"
      
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = ws.Range(SourceFirstCellAddress)
    Dim slCell As Range
    Set slCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, sfCell.Column).End(xlUp)
    If slCell.Row < sfCell.Row Then Exit Sub ' no data
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range(sfCell, slCell)
    
    Dim TestWert As Double: TestWert = ws.Range(TestCellAddress).Value
    Dim k As Long: k = 1
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        If IsNumeric(sCell) Then
            If sCell.Value = TestWert * k Then
                ws.Cells(sCell.Row, DestinationColumn).Value = k
                k = k + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next sCell
    
    MsgBox "Results written.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**Argumented**

```vb
Sub TestMamTEST()
    
    Const wsName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SourceFirstCellAddress As String = "A1"
    Const TestCellAddress As String = "G2"
    Const DestinationColumn As String = "B"
      
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = ws.Range(SourceFirstCellAddress)

    TestMam sfCell, TestCellAddress, DestinationColumn
    ' or just:
    'TestMam sfCell, "G2", "B"

End Sub

Sub TestMamOneLinerTEST()
    TestMam ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1"), "G2", "B"
End Sub

Sub TestMam( _
        ByVal SourceFirstCell As Range, _
        ByVal TestCellAddress As String, _
        ByVal DestinationColumn As String)
      
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = SourceFirstCell.Worksheet
    
    Dim slCell As Range
    Set slCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, SourceFirstCell.Column).End(xlUp)
    If slCell.Row < SourceFirstCell.Row Then Exit Sub ' no data
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range(SourceFirstCell, slCell)
    
    Dim TestWert As Double: TestWert = ws.Range(TestCellAddress).Value
    Dim k As Long: k = 1
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    
    For Each sCell In srg.Cells
        If IsNumeric(sCell) Then
            If sCell.Value = TestWert * k Then
                ws.Cells(sCell.Row, DestinationColumn).Value = k
                k = k + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next sCell
    
    MsgBox "Results written.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! This looks much like what i meant to implement. Gonnna add it to my project now.